# Keeping NSTextAlignmentLeft or NSTextAlignmentRight in Localized strings/ constant place

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-alignment

I have one view controller where I have many UITextField and the app is bi-lingual.

So what I am doing is as below.

```
if ([localize(@"myLang") isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
    firstNameTF.textAlignment = lastNameTF.textAlignment = phoneNumberTF.textAlignment = homeTF.textAlignment = areaTF.textAlignment = blockTF.textAlignment = streetTF.textAlignment = houseTF.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
} else {
    firstNameTF.textAlignment = lastNameTF.textAlignment = phoneNumberTF.textAlignment = homeTF.textAlignment = areaTF.textAlignment = blockTF.textAlignment = streetTF.textAlignment = houseTF.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
}
```

What I wanted to do is write just one line like below.

```
firstNameTF.textAlignment = lastNameTF.... = VALUE_FROM_LOCALIZATION;
```

Is it doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could make a macro like-

```
#define VALUE_FROM_LOCALIZATION ([localize(@"myLang") isEqualToString:@"en"]) ? NSTextAlignmentLeft : NSTextAlignmentRight
```

then use it exactly like the one line you posted.